# What keeps caching from working in WebMatrix?

Tags: asp.net, iis, razor, webmatrix

I have a number of pages in a WebMatrix Razor ASP.Net site where I have added one line of code:

```
    Response.OutputCache(600);
```

From reading about it I had assumed that this mean that IIS would create a cache of the html produced by the page, serve that html for the next 10 minutes, and after 10 minutes when the next request came in, it would run the code again.

Now the page is being fetched as part of an timed jquery call.  The time code in the client runs every minute.  The code there is very simple:

```
        function wknTimer4() {
        $.get('PerfPanel', function(data) {
        $('#perfPanel').html(data);

        });
```

It occasionally appears to cache, but when i look at the number of database queries done during the 10 minute period, i might have well over 100 database queries.  I know the caching isn't working the way I expect.  Does the cache only work for a single session?  Is there some other limitation?

Update:  it really shouldn't matter what the client does, whether it fetches the page through a jQuery call, or straight html.  If the server is caching, it doesn't matter what the client does.

Update 2:  complete code dumped here.  Boring stuff:

```
@{  

    var db = Database.Open("LOS"); 
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM LXD_funding ORDER BY LXDOrder"; 
    // cache the results of this page for 600 seconds
    Response.OutputCache(600); 


 }



@foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString) ){

    <h1>
    <a href="Dashboard/FundingDetails/@row.Status">@row.quotes</a>  Loans @row.NALStatus, oldest     @(NALWorkTime.WorkDays(row.StatusChange,DateTime.Now)) days

    </h1>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions about how OutputCache works are correct.  Can you check firebug or chrome tools to look at the outgoing requests hitting your page?  If you're using jQuery, sometimes people set the cache property on the $.get or $.ajax to false, which causes the request to the page to have a funky trailing querystring.  I've made the mistake of setting this up globally to fix some issues with jQuery and IE:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

The other to look at here is the grouping of DB calls.  Are you just making a lot of calls with one request?  Are you executing a db command in a loop, within another reader? Code in this case would be helpful.

Good luck, I hope this helps!

Comment: Response.OutputCache has an optional parameter called varyByParams that would cause it to cache different html for different parameters.  In my case, even if the jquery is doing the funky trailing querystring, the server should cache and return the same result.  There's one database call within the single cshtml page, so there's no loops or decisions that would cause the query to get executed multiple times.  Perhaps it's not looking at the query, but caching different html based on the simplemembership cookie.

Comment: In retrospect, I wouldn't want it to cache html for everyone exactly the same, i want it to only do it for the allowed roles.  However, the decision about the roles is within the cshtml file that i want cached...  thus, I believe you shouldn't use the OutputCache function if you care about security.  Instead, i plan to cache the data so i don't make an expensive database call, and then run the cshtml code without calling Response.OutputCache.

Comment: I awarded a bounty to Justin Beckwith because his answer was best, but i still think there's an explanation out there somewhere  :)

Comment: If you want to offer up a code sample, I'd be happy to work with the asp.net guys to figure out what's up.